# How to forward network traffic through Docker OpenVPN Client?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn

My current setup has a docker image running OpenVPN Client that connects to an Access Server in AWS. If I run the command:

```
docker exec <container-id> bash
```

I can get into the OpenVPN Container itself and can ping relevant IP's connected to the OpenVPN Server. My question is how would i tell the local machine(ubuntu) to forward all local traffic, say I'm just doing a ping from outside the container, to go through the Docker0 interface and through the OpenVPN Client?

I've tried setting up a webproxy but I believe setting up the webproxy was to help with other containers forwarding traffic to the OpenVPN container, whereas i need to forward traffic from the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add routes from your host machine to the destinations you want to be forwarded via the OpenVPN tunnel so that they point to your Docker container IP address.

For example:

```
route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 172.17.17.1
```

where `192.168.1.0/24` is the IP network you want to route via Docker container's local IP address `172.17.17.1`.

If you cannot control the routing of the machines at the other end of tunnel, you need to set up a reverse route on those machines. Another option is to set up NAT on the Docker container.

Comment: Whenever i tried to ping after adding the route its still not possible, is there a different route i should be adding?

Comment: Did you use correct IP addresses? Did you add the corresponding reverse route on the destination machine you tried to ping to?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen What is the reverse rule?

Comment: If you have two networks, 192.168.0.0/24 (a) and 192.168.1.0/24 (b), where 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1 are the routers. Then on network a, you need to have route `192.168.1.0/24` via `192.168.0.1`, and on network b, `192.168.0.0/24` via `192.168.1.1`. The latter one is the reverse rule.

Comment: Regarding the necessity of the "reverse rule", what if the remote network is not within your local networks (i.e., a network halfway around the world)?

Answer (score 0):

As @tero-kilkanen explained, you have to add a route from host to AWS instance via container with OpenVPN clinet.

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 172.18.0.2
```

Where `172.18.0.2` is your docker container IP and `192.168.1.0/24` is subnet in AWS.

Next steps will depend on Access Server configuration setup in AWS
The easiest way of troubleshooting will be to install `tcpdump` on remote host instance in AWS. Then start to ping remote instance from your host machine i.e. ping `192.168.1.2` where `192.168.1.2` IP of the remote instance. Then on remote instance run `tcpdump -nn -i any` and watch ping requests coming in and notice IP address they come from. If this IP is not OpenVPN IP i.e. `10.8.0.2` but `172.18.0.1` which your host machine IP the docker network. Then will have login to remote instance and add a route from AWS back to your host.
I.e. `ip route add 172.18.0.2 via 192.168.1.1` where `192.168.1.1` is AWS router/gateway IP of the OpenVPN Access Server.